# static members and consts

Tags: c++, static, constants

```
class a
{
protected:
  const int _ID;

public:
  a::a(int id){};
  a::top(int num);
};

class b : public a
{
  static int ok;
  b::b(int id):a(id){};
  a::top(ok);
}

int main()
{
  int t=5;
  b opj=b(t);
}
```

first why i get this compile error that solved only when i remove the const

non-static const member ‘const int Student::_ID’, can't use default assignment operator - 
 instantiated from ‘void std::vector::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Student, _Alloc = std::allocator]’

second

i have anther problem

undefined reference to b::ok

Comment: Please have the decency and format your source code in a well readable manner. This also holds true for the question text itself.

Comment: @Jim Brissom: Cut Mati some slack - looks like he/she is a new user. Better yet, help do the formatting so he/she can see it. @mati: here is the formatting reference: [http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Otaku no he just doesn't care about a real answer or he just makes fun of SO users or both. Just look at his other questions. I'm not going to waste my time tying to teach a troll how to press a "format-it" button.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: I had no idea he was so malicious. I looked through his other threads and couldn't notice anything other than someone whose first language is not English and someone who doesn't really know the ins and outs of SO yet. You seem to be privy to a much deeper evil here than I am...

Comment: first thank you all for your answers second i cant understend jim why you think i try to make fun of you? and last how i mark that the problem solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second first:  `b::ok` has been *declared*, but not *defined*.  Someplace, (preferably b.cpp), you need to add:

```
  int b::ok;
```

As for your first problem,  `_ID` is *const*, it value cannot be changed -- but, you never give it a value to start with.  You have to assign it an initial value:

```
  protected:
      const int _ID = 1234;
```

Now, you really should defined _ID as well, as we did with b::ok, but since it is `const`, the compiler may let you get away without doing that (some conditions apply).

Answer (score 4):

This code has too may reasons to report compile errors.

- In C++ you are not allowed to use qualified names when declaring class methods, so your `a::a` and `a::top` in the definition of class `a` are flat-out illegal.
- What method declarations without a return type are supposed to mean is not clear either.
- A declaration of `a::top` in `b` makes no sense either. What is it doing there? And what was the intent of having `a::top(ok)` in the middle of the class definition?

In other words, you code makes no sense whatsoever. It is not even a remotely C++ code. If you feed this into a C++ compiler the results will be pretty much as meaningful as if you fed Shakespeare's "Hamlet" into a C++ compiler. It is not possible to say what's wrong with the code, when *everything* is wrong. If this is some other language, please, tag it accordingly instead of [C++].

Answer (score 2):

Since _ID is const, it has to be initialized in the constructor/base member initialization list. Sort of like this:

```
a::a(int id) : _ID(5) {};
```

However, I got a ton of errors when I tried to build this. Are you sure you pasted the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question first: ok is a static member and needs to be initialized as such. Include a line similar to:

```
int b::ok = 0;
```

...in the implementation file for your class b.

As for the _ID member: You declared _ID to be a constant, but you did not define it, i.e. you did not provide a value for the constant. Since it is constant and you are not allowed to change it later - how do you expect _ID to take a value then?

Also, there are some other "funny" things going on in your source code that make me advise you to (re-)read an  introductory text.